# ASP.NET authorization configuration - CMS backend user can't access resources

Tags: asp.net, authorization, owin, umbraco7

I'm running an Umbraco instance. In order to prevent unauthorized users to download media files (like pdf docs) using a direct URL like http://mysite.xy/media/4343/sometext.pdf I used a web.config file in the media folder:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

This works perfectly for frontend users. But for users logged into the backend the pictures don't show up and pdf files refuse download. If I remove the web.config file (access for everyone) the pictures appear in the backend and pdf download is possible.

I'm using Umbraco 7.4.3. In former versions (7.1.6) the behavior was correct. As far as I know Umbraco switched forms authentication from ASP.NET web forms to OWin / OAuth.

Does anybody have an idea, what I can do to allow backend users access to media files?

MM

Comment: You could use MediaProtect instead https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/media-protect/

Comment: Media Protect doesn't fit our needs. My understandig is, that it should be possible to make a restricted folder visible for backend users or roles. I think, there is a way to do that, but I don't know, how.